# How to Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines According to styled texts only?

Tags: notepad++

I have a text list file like following:

```
NEW! Most Popular 001.jpg - 1227 px - 244 px - 2507 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 002.jpg - 1227 px - 244 px - 2507 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 003.jpg - 1227 px - 244 px - 2507 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 004.jpg - 1227 px - 244 px - 2507 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 005.jpg - 1226 px - 244 px - 2508 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 006.jpg - 1339 px - 293 px - 2395 px - 1765 px
NEW! Most Popular 007.jpg - 1316 px - 290 px - 2418 px - 1760 px
NEW! Most Popular 008.jpg - 1316 px - 290 px - 2418 px - 1760 px
NEW! Most Popular 009.jpg - 1272 px - 232 px - 2462 px - 1760 px
NEW! Most Popular 010.jpg - 1272 px - 232 px - 2462 px - 1760 px
NEW! Most Popular 011.jpg - 1332 px - 228 px - 2402 px - 1764 px
```

Now I want to Bookmark all texts after second `-` using `.jpg - .*` regex and make `Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines` on bookmarked texts using notepad++ `edit > Line Operations`

this mean only following must keep in my list:

```
NEW! Most Popular 001.jpg - 1227 px - 244 px - 2507 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 005.jpg - 1226 px - 244 px - 2508 px - 1748 px
NEW! Most Popular 006.jpg - 1339 px - 293 px - 2395 px - 1765 px
NEW! Most Popular 008.jpg - 1316 px - 290 px - 2418 px - 1760 px
NEW! Most Popular 010.jpg - 1272 px - 232 px - 2462 px - 1760 px
NEW! Most Popular 011.jpg - 1332 px - 228 px - 2402 px - 1764 px
```

I really sorry but I didn't find any solution for this
I hope you completely understand what I want do

Comment: You need a script.  This is not a job for an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^-]+-[^-]+-)(.+$)(?:\R(?1)\2)+`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(           # start group 1
    [^-]+       # 1 or more non hyphen
    -           # 1 hyphen
    [^-]+       # 1 or more non hyphen
    -           # 1 hyphen
)           # end group 1
(.+$)       # group 2 any character until end of line
(?:         # non capture group
\R          # any kind of linebreak
    (?1)        # same pattern as defined in group 1
    \2          # same occurrence of value contained in group 2
)+          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]